# BULK INSERT using format file and dat file

Tags: sql-server

I generated a dat file with a format file in SQL 2014, now I'm trying to use a BULK INSERT but I receive this error:

```
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" supplied invalid metadata for column "CallTime". The datatype required a precision, but none was supplied.
```

The column is defined as string like this:

```
[CallTime] sparse nvarchar(20) null
```

The call is like this:

```
BULK INSERT [invc].[MyTable]
FROM 'D:\Temp\file.dat'
WITH 
  (
    FORMATFILE = 'D:\Temp\format.fmt'
    ,KEEPNULLS
  );
```

My format file looks like this (I know I have more columns defined):

[image]

The values on that columns looks like this:

```
22:26
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error, besides, the table is a big table with millions of records, what's the best way to generate the file, dat or text?

Comment: The message indicates that the process has mapped CallTime to a decimal field, however, the schema you posted only has one decimal field, CallDuration. I would double check that again.

Comment: Hi Ross, in case is pointed to a decimal field, where do I need to set the precision? I'm generating the format file automatically like this: bcp invc.MyTable format nul -T -N -S MyServer -f format.fmt

Comment: I forgot to mention that the table has an identity column that I'm excluding from the list of columns, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I was able to generate the file including the identity column, so problem fixed!